# Freeform plugin conditional rules not working

Tags: plugin-freeform, craft-pro

I have 3 select fields in my form - Select A, Select B and Select C. I want Select B & C to be hidden by default. If Select A option is not X, then show Select B. If option Y is not selected in Select B field then show Select C.

This is what the conditional rule on the form looks like.

[image: Note that Type of Loan is Select A, while What to know about this loan is Select B]

Note that Type of Loan is Select A, while What to know about this loan is Select B.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Cos this rule isn't working. I am using version 3.8.4

Comment: Could you please extend on what exactly „Not working“ means?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Johannes. However I noticed I didn't {{ field.rulesHtmlData }} to the div wrapper for each field inside the {% for field in row %}. That has been sorted out ever since.